# How can i upload complicated json data from Editor.js to firebase firestore?

Tags: reactjs, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Im creating a blog app using react JS and editor.js. but if you used editor.js it returns the data as a json object. but i'm connected to firebase and i wanted to add these data to my firestore. as i mentioned in the title the json it returns is complicated.

```
{
  time: 1683888680625,
  blocks: [
    {
      id: "mhTl6ghSkV",
      type: "paragraph",
      data: {
        text: "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this picture you can see it in action. Then, try a demo ",} ,} ,
    {
      id: "l98dyx3yjb",
      type: "header",
      data: {
        text: "Key features",
        level: 3,} ,} ,
    {
      id: "os_YI4eub4",
      type: "list",
      data: {
        type: "unordered",
        items: [
          "It is a block-style editor",
          "It returns clean data output in JSON",
          "Designed to be extendable and pluggable with a <a 
          href="https://editorjs.io/creating-a-block-tool">simple API</a>",] ,} ,} ,
    {
      id: "TcUNySG15P",
      type: "paragraph",
      data: {
        text: "Workspace in classic editors is made of a single contenteditable element, used to create different HTML markups. Editor.js workspace consists of separate Blocks: paragraphs, headings, images, lists, quotes, etc. Each of them is an independent <sup data-tune="footnotes">1</sup> contenteditable element (or more complex structure) provided by Plugin and united by Editor's Core.",} ,
        tunes: {
          footnotes: [
            "It works more stable then in other WYSIWYG editors. Same time it has smooth and well-known arrow navigation behavior like classic editors.",] ,} ,} ,
    {
      id: "XKNT99-qqS",
      type: "attaches",
      data: {
        file: {
          url: "https://drive.google.com/user/catalog/my-file.pdf",
          size: 12902,
          name: "file.pdf",
          extension: "pdf",} ,
          title: "My file",} ,} ,
   {
      id: "hZAjSnqYMX",
      type: "image",
      data: {
        file: {
        url: "assets/codex2x.png",} ,
        withBorder: false,
        withBackground: false,
        stretched: true,
        caption: "CodeX Code Camp 2019",} ,} ,] ,}
```

the more complicated part is to upload the image/files to the storage, then update the url in the json finally upload that json to firestore according to their order?

Comment: Can you add the Editor.js in your question.

Comment: @DominicT i haven't used it yet. i checked their docs and i wanted to know how to push all datas including the files to firebase before using it.

Comment: For us to proceed you need to provide [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).